# Angular/Typescript - Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I get error Element implicitly has an 'any' type because index expression is not of type 'number' when I wont to use selected_team value like key.
HTML:

```
<option *ngFor="let player of teams[selected_team]" value="player.name">...</option>
```

Code:

```
selected_team = "";
teams: OverviewTeamType[] = [];
```

Interface:

```
export interface OverviewTeamType {
  name: string;
  players: [
    {
      age: number;
      birthday: string;
      height: number;
      hokejczId: number;
      id: string;
      name: string;
      position: string;
      stick: string;
      surname: string;
      weight: number;
      yearOfBirth: number;
    }
  ];
  shortName: string;
  shortcut: string;
}
```

Comment: Rightfully so - you are indexing an array with a string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want. `teams.find(team => team.name === selectedTeam).players` instead of `teams[selectedTeam]` in the ngFor statement.

```
<option *ngFor="let player of teams.find(team => team.name === selectedTeam).players" value="player.name">...</option>

export interface OverviewTeamType {
  name: string;
  players: {
      age: number;
      birthday: string;
      height: number;
      hokejczId: number;
      id: string;
      name: string;
      position: string;
      stick: string;
      surname: string;
      weight: number;
      yearOfBirth: number;
    }[];
  shortName: string;
  shortcut: string;
}

selected_team = "";
teams: OverviewTeamType[] = [];
```

Comment: This will cause "Bindings cannot contain assignments at column 32" error and is also a bad practice to use expressions in angular bindings. But I solved the whole problem a different way.